# Risk of using Apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I am now exploring to use Apache's mod_proxy's directive, eg ProxyPass, as part of solution for cross-domain scripting restriction (for html/ajax/flash code). However, I am afraid by enabling mod_proxy, I would risk having the server as open proxy.

What's the risk, and how to minimize the risk, in short?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really programming-related, I think... seems more like an IT thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you specifically mentioned ProxyPass, I'll assume you're using mod_proxy as a reverse proxy.

If that's the case, just make sure ProxyRequests is off.  It isn't needed for reverse proxies.

In a forward proxy configuration, if you were to enable ProxyRequests without setting access restrictions (i.e., which hosts/networks are allowed to use the proxy) you could very easily wind up with an open proxy.

See the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure to set **ProxyRequests** to **Off**:

This prevents Apache from acting as a forward proxy server (which is where the concern about an open proxy comes in), but does not affect its use as a reverse proxy using ProxyPass